# How to display image in ImageView as original resolution / size

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

Here is my code:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_doc_image);
                            Picasso.with(AddDocActivity.this).load(url)
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.hourglass)
                                    .into(img);
```

Layout

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_doc_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
```

My image after downloading is much smaller than the original when I display in my image view. My question, is there a way to show the image in its original large size using Picasso? Note:  I already tried fit(), .resize() and scaleType="center" .
What I ultimately would like to do is be able to scroll the large image in its (**original high resolution format**) horizontally and vertically (if it does not fit on my screen)....but I can't even get it to show larger than a thumbnail at this point...not sure what I don't understand about image downloads in Android or what am doing wrong here.

UPDATE: 7/31/2015
I rolled my own code to download the pic from the server, then viewed the pic on my device and it is much smaller than the original. I can't seem to figure out why my image is getting shrunken down when downloaded to my device --- is this by design in Android or something I'm doing?

UPDATE 8/03/2015
I loaded the same image locally and it is the correct size so that confirms my ImageView attributes are not doing anything to shrink my image.

Comment: What's your original photo size in pixels?

Comment: @Sharj 596 width   x  817height   (1.04 MB) .

Comment: 596px width  x   817px height

Comment: It is quite strange, I am using same lib from last 2 years but never faced this issue, as a try remove .placeholder(R.drawable.hourglass) line and let's see what will be the output.

Comment: Are you familiar with px vs dp? If you check your 596px photo on a high dpi phone it will look very small. If you see the same photo on low dpi phone it will look around 596px.

Comment: removing .placeholder(R.drawable.hourglass) does nothing. My pic on server is 1.04MB when its downloaded to device it is 32k ---- it that supposed to happen?

Comment: Quite strange...if possible then give me your image url so that I also try.

Comment: http://i.imgsafe.org/t/162ca26.png